# Use output of an operation in my shiny UI

Tags: r, shiny, r-caret

I have an observeEvent where i do some preprocessing to my reactive data:

```
observeEvent(input$preprocess_btn,{
    req(input$imputation_numeric, input$imputation_categorical)
    
      object_recipe <- recipe(as.formula(paste(input$variables, "~ .")), train_data())
      
      **
      preprocessing steps here
      **

      trained_recipe <- prep(object_recipe, training = train_data())
      
      print(trained_recipe) #This shows the desired output, but on console
      
      train_data_prep(bake(trained_recipe, new_data = train_data()))
      test_data_prep(bake(trained_recipe, new_data = test_data()))
      
  })
```

The desired output as displayed on the code fragment would be:

> ── Recipe ────────────
>
> ── Inputs  Number of variables by role outcome:   1 predictor: 7
>
> ── Training information  Training data contained 713 data points and
> 148 incomplete rows.
>
> ── Operations   • Bagged tree imputation for: Age, SibSp, Parch, Fare
> | Trained  • Mode imputation for: Pclass, Sex, Embarked | Trained  •
> Sparse, unbalanced variable filter removed:  | Trained  •
> Centering for: Age, SibSp, Parch, Fare | Trained  • Scaling for: Age,
> SibSp, Parch, Fare | Trained  • Dummy variables from: Pclass, Sex,
> Embarked | Trained

Thing is I don't know how to pass it to a renderPrint because the variables can only be called inside the observeEvent, and tried storing It inside a reactiveVal but couldn't find success

Answer (score 1):

Store the output of the `observeEvent()` in a `reactiveValues()` then print that. You would need a UI element too of course.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(recipes)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("preprocess_btn", "Start Process"),
    verbatimTextOutput("textout")
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    rvals <- reactiveValues()

    observeEvent(input$preprocess_btn, {
      rec <- recipe(mtcars) %>%
        step_center(everything()) %>%
        step_scale(everything()) %>%
        check_missing(everything())

      rvals$trained_recipe <- tidy(rec)
    })

    output$textout <- renderPrint({
      rvals$trained_recipe
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: I did as u said, but instead of working as intended, it returned the desired output in Console but now It Is red

Comment: Sorry, had a typo. Use `reactiveValues()` not `reactiveVals()`. If you add an associated UI element like `verbatimTextOutput("textoutput")`, you should see it on the app, not console. You can change the UI output to be something else, like `textOutput()` or create a UI element with html tags.

Comment: I edited my answer to show a self contained example

Comment: i assumed the typo an corrected It first time no worries. Also used the verbatimTextOutput the first time . I know It's weird but the output is not showing in the app and is still in console but It's all red like when an error is printed. I know the references are not wrong because before pressing the button for the observeEvent() to execute there is a verbatim box with a "NULL" inside (because the reactiveValues is empty when created). It's only after the button is pressed when that NULL disappears and the output appears on Console but red

Comment: Would love to help you, but without a minimal reproducible example it's hard to identify what may be going on. Perhaps you could striip down your app to the minimum pieces that reproduce the problem?

Comment: used the edited example in your reply:

trained_recipe <- prep(object_recipe, training = train_data())
rvals$rval1 <- list(A = trained_recipe, B = head(train_data()))

then, outside the observeEvent:

output$trained_recipe_print_output <- renderPrint({
    rvals$rval1
  })

Inside the app, $A is empty and $B has the expected table.

The content expected in $A is in Console

Comment: What's the class of `trained_recipe`?

Comment: trained_recipe <- prep(object_recipe, training = train_data()) returns a recipe object, but what I want is the output originated in console when It is executed. print(trained_recipe) shows It in console as I said in the original post, so my first thought was to use capture.output(print(trained_recipe)) and then use renderPrint to that, but that returns character(0)

Comment: Neither `capture.output()` nor `sink()` worked for me. But you can access some of the info  with `tidy(trained_recipe)` and print that. That has some of the info in the output, but not all.